# Flash content not loading using headless selenium on server

Tags: python, selenium, flash

I am running selenium webdriver (firefox) using python on a headless server.  I am using pyvirtualdisplay to start and stop the Xvnc display to grab the image of the sites I am visiting.  This is working great except flash content is not loading on the pages (I can tell because I am taking screenshots of the pages and I just see empty space where flash content should be on the screenshots).

When I run the same program on my local unix machine, the flash content loads just fine.  I have installed flash on my server, and have libflashplayer.so in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins.  The only difference seems to be that I am using the Xvnc display on the server (unless plash wasn't installed properly?  but I believe it was since I used to get a message asking me to install flash when I viewed a site that had flash content but since installing flash I dont get that message anymore).

Does anyone have any ideas or experience with this- is there a trick to getting flash to load using a firefox webdriver on a headless server?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I needed to use selenium to scroll down the page to load all the content.